# How do I pass use Authorize from Paypal Orders API in my method & what should I return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a pending fetch request that is waiting for the authorize method below to execute on my backend.

I need to use the authorize request details from PayPal orders api from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_authorize)
and implement that in the method below. I have attempted to do that below but I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
async authorize(): Promise<PAR> {
    var res = HTTPClient.request(
      'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders',
      {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
            'Bearer access-token',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          intent: 'AUTHORIZE',
          purchase_units: [
            { amount: { currency_code: 'USD', value: '100' } },
          ],
        }),
      },
    );

    return (await res).responseText;
  }
```

Sorry if I'm not able to explain it properly, please feel free to ask for anything else you may need for this. This is my first time doing something in TypeScript & I got into node very very recently too.

Comment: Looks like you need to create a ParsedAuthorizationResponse and set its values based on the "res" you get back from your HTTP request. Seems straightforward.

Comment: Do you mean something like "return new ParsedAuthorizationResponse(here I should check what the statusCode/responseText is and then maybe use ternaries to set the value for ParsedAuthorizationResponse)"? Also, could you take a look at my authorize method and see if my implementation of authorize request done correctly? (acc to what the paypal api doc is expecting) I'd really appreciate it

Comment: clientid:secret needs to be base64 encoded.  You should assign your new PAR to a variable, set its values, then return it.

Comment: Thank you! Understood the PAR part. Just realized that I've actually hardcoded the Bearer Access Token. Do you think I should make an initial http to regenerate it everytime from client and secret and then pass it to the above http request or is putting it there like that okay for testing purposes for now? Sorry for a lot of questions, I haven't done this before

Comment: Access tokens usually expire after 9 hours, so draw your own conclusions

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you also take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039009/how-do-i-extract-orderid-from-this-object-response-pass-it-to-another-function
It seems trivial but I can't seem to do it for some reason :/