# How do I extract OrderID from this object/response & pass it to another function onApproval? (Paypal API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, paypal

Please see this example -> https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

The createOrder func there returns this ->

```
{"id":"8GS56714S6789541X","intent":"CAPTURE","status":"CREATED","purchase_units":[{"reference_id":"default","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"88.44"},"payee":{"email_address":"barco.03-facilitator@gmail.com","merchant_id":"YQZCHTGHUK5P8"}}],"create_time":"2021-02-04T02:47:04Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8GS56714S6789541X","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=8GS56714S6789541X","rel":"approve","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8GS56714S6789541X","rel":"update","method":"PATCH"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/8GS56714S6789541X/capture","rel":"capture","method":"POST"}]}
```

I want to extract the id field from it and then pass it on to onApprove, in which I want to use it to pass to another function.

This is what I tried changing in the example link above to achieve what I want but I'm doing it very wrong because I can't even see the paypal button anymore lol

```
let orderID = 0;
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({

            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) { //this gives back the response I posted above
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '88.44'
                        }
                    }]
                }).then((details) => { 
                    orderID = details.id;
                })
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function() {
                console.log(orderID);
                letsAuthorize(orderID); //this is some function that I wanna pass the orderID to
            }
            
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Please note that in the example, they are also capturing onApprove but I don't want to capture. I only want to get the orderID from the createOrder response and then pass it into the function in onApprove.

(in a nutshell, I wanna get the orderid that createorder sends in it's response and pass it to onApprove function where I wanna use it to call another function that goes to my backend implementation of authorize)

Answer (score 0):

> Please see this example -> https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

As you're using node.js and typescript, shouldn't you be using the server API samples at: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

(make one server route for 'Create Order', and one for 'Capture Order', both of which should return JSON)

Paired with the approval flow example at, rather: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

Anyway, to really answer your question, onApprove should be:

`onApprove: function(data, actions) {`

It will be called with the orderID in `data`.

Comment: I've been specifically asked to create the order at client side instead of server side, that's why I was using that example as reference. What I need to do, in the bigger picture, is create the order at client side > get the order ID by passing stuff as options in the button & onApprove, call a function > that function sends fetch request to /api/authorize on my server and runs the authorize command from the other question & returns a response I think.  There are also seperate methods that I need to implement, like just authorize, for cancel order & capture order.

Comment: Just tried replacing onApprove with your suggestion. It seems that ".then((details) => { orderID = details.id; });" after the createOrder is causing the popup window to crash, so it never really gets to the graphql part (or onApproval) in the network requests :/

Comment: The window will close immediately if it doesn't get a valid id in response

Comment: "I've been specifically asked to create the order at client side instead of server side" -- I see you people like to live dangerously. Good luck.

Comment: Sadly, it's a part of a coding assignment I've been given, so there's not much upto my choice :/ I checked the response in the network tab of chrome tools & it seems to have a valid id. I feel like I'm doing that "then" part wrong for some reason, it doesn't seem to get the id through details.id, comes out as undefined. Anyways, I really appreciate all the help though man, thank you very much. I probably need to play around with it more & find a way to make it work somehow

Comment: Are you aware of any actions.order.___ I can request for onApprove other than create/authorize/capture that gives back a response with order ID? That would really help!

Comment: It's just `data.orderID`, the first parameter to onApprove

Comment: As far as creating an order on the client side and attempting to authorize or capture it on the server, I believe you can expect the error `{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"The token passed in was not found in the system"}`